# MySQL count logins AND return latest login

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a very simple table:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| time     | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| username | varchar(120) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| ip       | varchar(40)  | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| failed   | varchar(40)  | NO   | MUL |         |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm looking to query for a few specific users and I want both a count of logins and the most recent login (if any logins exist).  I've tried various combinations of "GROUP BY" and nothing is quite working.

My simple count query is this:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*), username FROM logins WHERE username='foo@bar.com' and failed='0' group by username;
```

How can I still get a single row back that contains both a count and the last login?

Bonus points if it turns the timestamp into human-friendly format.

edit: The first answer seems the clearest to me, and that worked well.

I also came up with this, which seems to work and returns in about the same amount of time, but I'm not sure what I'm doing there with the nested SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), username (SELECT MAX(time)) FROM logins WHERE username='foo@bar.com' AND failed='0' GROUP BY username;
```

And to get a human-readable time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), username (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(time))) FROM logins WHERE username='foo@bar.com' AND failed='0' GROUP BY username;
```

Both this version and the more proper looking query in the first answer take about 2m 27s (the table has about 161M rows).

Comment: marginally related: did you painstakingly create that table, or did you use some vim/emacs voodoo to write it up in a jiffy?

Comment: That's just the output of "explain logins" in the mysql client. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Max(time)` will give you the latest login time.  See the full query bellow

```
SELECT username, 
       COUNT(*)    AS `count`, 
       Max(`time`) AS `latest` 
FROM   logins 
WHERE  username = 'foo@bar.com' 
       AND failed = '0' 
GROUP  BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT count(*), username,time 
FROM logins 
WHERE username='foo@bar.com' and failed='0' 
group by username 
order by time desc
```

OR

```
SELECT count(*), username,max(time) 
FROM logins 
WHERE username='foo@bar.com' and failed='0' 
group by username
```

Comment: thanks, second form seems to work fine and does give the proper timestamp without the "order by".

Answer (score 0):

```
select username, count(username) count, max(time) time 
from logins where username in ("a","b") group by username
```